# Woocommerce - How to select multiple value in attributes ?

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

My first type of product is variable product with attributese. 
My second type of product is a box with several products. As I don't have stocks, I thought that the choice of products to put in the box, I could set attribute.

The problem is that on a product page you can select one attribute at a time. I need the client to select five attributes at once !

How can I do to "allow" the selection of multiple attributes ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to set attributes for each of the different products in the "box"?

Comment: Nope. My first type of product is variable product with attributes. My second type of product is a box.  For details a box contains 6 pastries. And the customer must choose 6 pastries he wants. As I don't have stocks, I thought that the choice of products to put in the box, I could set attribute.

The problem is that on a product page you can select one attribute at a time. I need the client to select 6 attributes at once !

Do you think there would be another solution instead of multiple attributes ? Thanks you !!